# как загрузить картинку из базы данных на админ-сайт

Tags: javascript, jquery

Друзья есть база данных из которой мне надо выводить на сайте картинку. То есть при клике на кнопку должна появляться картинка из базы данных. 
Есть такой код:

```
var row = '<tr>' + '<td>' + object.get('username') + '</td>' +
                   '<td class="seeDiploma">' + object.get('diploma') + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + object.get('qualification') + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' +
                         '<div class="acept">accept</div>' +
                         '<div class="reject">reject</div>' +
                     '</td>'
                      '</tr>'
```

'' + object.get('diploma') + '' эта строка и должна выводить картинку, а выводит    [object Object]
Подскажите что я делаю не так? Я еще не очень селен в Js

Comment: А в каком виде хранится у вас картинка в БД, сслыка на файл или base64 или что-то еще?

Comment: в формате jpg, а сама база данных это PARSE DASHBOARD

Comment: То есть в object.get('diploma') у вас получается путь до файла на сервере?

Comment: а где и должен быть путь? извините за тупёж, я новичок.

Comment: object.get('diploma') diploma это непосредственно название ячеек в которой будут храниться фото дипломов потенциальных преподавателей

Comment: Файлы можно хранить по разному, как файл и указывать к нему путь, или же как строка, в которой будет набор пикселей по цветам (образно говоря), но судя по всему у вас первый вариант, хотя если вы напишете  что конкретно выводит object.get('diploma'), для этого можно вставить такую конструкцию в код console.log(object.get('diploma')); перед тем кодом который вы предоставили и посмотреть в консоли браузера нажав f12

Comment: да. вы абсолютно правы, у меня в diploma будет файл.

Comment: то есть мне надо указать путь к файлу, но тут же вопрос - где прописать путь? и еще один вопрос - файлов (скринов дипломов) будет возможно много (количество соответственное количеству непроверенных потенциальных преподавателей), и как сделать так что бы выводились все картинки, а не только одна к которой задан путь? Спасибо вам за помощь

Comment: А если вы хотите вывести несколько изображений, то вам нужно получить весь список файлов, а потом в цикле их выводить, такой же строкой, как у вас это реализовано сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в object.get('diploma') находится ссылка на файл, то вам надо получить ее из этого объекта, так как у вас объект, а не строка с ссылкой. В Вашем примере надо будет заменить object.get('diploma') на следующий код:

```
'<img src="' + object.get('diploma') + '">'
```

Чтобы получить конкретно ссылку из object.get('diploma'), то нужно в конце поставить точку и дописать нужное свойство объекта, которое у вас отвечает а ссылку object.get('diploma').src. Объект можно вывести в консоль с помощью следующего кода:

```
console.log(object.get('diploma'));
```

открыть консоль по f12 и посмотреть внизу, что у вас из свойств объекта является путем к файлу и это подставить вместо "src".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: '<td class="seeDiploma">'<img src="' + object.get('diploma') + '">'</td>' +
делал так и не работает

Comment: '<td class="seeDiploma">' + object.get('diploma').url
:
"http://46.101.79.85:1337/parse/files/lp/ed3deeeef6c877468047617680fcaee2_404.jpg"+ '</td>' +
тоже не работает. Подскажите где я туплю? Что я пишу и делаю не так?

Comment: @emankinn А вы можете вывести свой объект object.get('diploma') в консоль, чтобы понять его структуру?

Comment: e {_name: "ed3deeeef6c877468047617680fcaee2_404.jpg", _url: "http://46.101.79.85:1337/parse/files/lp/ed3deeeef6c877468047617680fcaee2_404.jpg"}
_name
:
"ed3deeeef6c877468047617680fcaee2_404.jpg"
_url
:
"http://46.101.79.85:1337/parse/files/lp/ed3deeeef6c877468047617680fcaee2_404.jpg"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: это то что выводиться в консоли

Comment: '<img src="' + object.get('diploma')._url + '">' попробуйте так, должно сработать

Comment: '<td class="seeDiploma">'<img src="' + object.get('diploma')._url + '">' </td>' +
так не срабатывает

Comment: А в консоли есть ошибка какая-нибудь?

Comment: есть две
1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchUsers is not defined
    at index.html:32

Comment: исправил все ошибки. Долго не мог понять в чем проблема, а оказалось что нужно было поставить кавычки в нужном месте. Теперь консоль не выдает ошибок, но к сожалению по прежнему ну подгружаются картинки из базы данных.

Comment: '<td class="seeDiploma">' + '<img src="' + object.get('diploma')._url + '">' + '</td>'
это код который не выводит ошибки, но при этом не подгружает из базы данных нужные картинки.

Comment: спасибо Sergey Glazirin за помощь. Разобрался.